# Compiling PyQt5 using FBS: Linking to libraries whose path cannot be found

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, freeze, fbs

I am working on an GUI using PyQt5 and am using FBS to create the executable. The code runs fine when "FBS run" is used. But FBS freeze throws up a few errors and the resulting app does not run.
The errors are below:

```
46255 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DCore.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DCore (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
46255 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DRender.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DRender (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
46255 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DLogic.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DLogic (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
46651 ERROR: Can not find path ./QtGamepad.framework/Versions/5/QtGamepad (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46651 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DAnimation.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DAnimation (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46651 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DInput.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DInput (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46652 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DCore.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DCore (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46652 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DRender.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DRender (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46652 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DLogic.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DLogic (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
46666 ERROR: Can not find path ./QtMultimediaQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaQuick (needed by /Users/xxxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/cfehome-t3sZTH9i/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.dylib)
```

I do have the path to these libraries. For instance: `/Users/xxxx/Qt/5.12.6/clang_64/lib/Qt3DRender.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DRender`

I would appreciate any guidance on how to update the path or place these libraries where they can be found for code compilation using FBS